# Double api request React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following React Component

```
export default function Header () {
  const { isSessionActive, isMenuOpen, isProfileMenuOpen, setIsMenuOpen, closeMenu, URL } = useContext(AppContext)
  const [profileData, setProfileData] = useState({})

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isSessionActive) return
    console.log('Enter in the useEffect')
    const token = window.localStorage.getItem('token')
    axios.get(`${URL}/users`, { headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` } })
      .then(result => setProfileData(result.data))
      .catch(error => console.log(error))
  }, [isSessionActive])

  const openMenu = () => {
    setIsMenuOpen(true)
  }

  return (
    //Rest of the Jsx code...
  )
}
```

As you can see, I have a `useEffect` to make a request to an API. The `console.log('Enter in the useEffect')` pops out just one time (which is the expected behavior), meaning the component only makes the request once.

The problem is, if I log all the requests that arrive at my API, it looks like the application is making the request twice (I don't make any requests to the API in any other part of the app).

Why is this happening? Is it normal? Because that means the server will have to handle twice the number of requests just because of this problem (imagine if I have multiple calls).

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Are you by chance using `<StrictMode>` and react 17 or earlier? Strict mode deliberately double-runs effects in development builds to help catch bugs, and before react 18 they had a hacky thing where they overwrote the console.log function to suppress the second log.

Comment: No, I remove it and if i had it, the console log would appear twice as well

Comment: Is one of those requests a CORS preflight request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If your API server and client are on different domains, the browser might be sending a CORS preflight request before the actual request. Check if the preflight request is also being logged on the server. This should also show up in the Network tab of browser devtools.
2. Check if there is any global Axios configuration or interceptors affecting the requests. You may want to try the inbuilt fetch API to make the request to rule out this case.

If these don't help then would need to know more to be able to say more.

Comment: I hadn't thought about that, the app is making 2 request, one with the OPTIONS method and other with the GET method, thank you, I forgot it